# How do I configure sphinx properly with autodoc in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc

This is the first time I give sphinx a try so I'm following this guide: https://daler.github.io/sphinxdoc-test/includeme.html. Running `make html` with [this Makefile](https://gist.github.com/fedebarabas/a91ea0db9702d3ab7b8018d71cce41f9) fails with `Error 1` showing the warning `DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated`.

Here's the complete traceback from the sphinx log file:

```
# Sphinx version: 1.4.9
# Python version: 3.5.2 (CPython)
# Docutils version: 0.12 release
# Jinja2 version: 2.8
# Last messages:
#   Running Sphinx v1.4.9
#   loading pickled environment...
#   done
#   building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
#   building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
#   updating environment:
#   0 added, 2 changed, 0 removed
#   reading sources... [ 50%] mainGUI
#   reading sources... [100%] modules
# Loaded extensions:
#   sphinx.ext.autodoc (1.4.9) from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py
#   alabaster (0.7.9) from /home/federico/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/alabaster/__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 244, in main
    app.build(opts.force_all, filenames)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 297, in build
    self.builder.build_update()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 251, in build_update
    'out of date' % len(to_build))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 265, in build
    self.doctreedir, self.app))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/environment.py", line 569, in update
    self._read_serial(docnames, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/environment.py", line 589, in _read_serial
    self.read_doc(docname, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/environment.py", line 738, in read_doc
    encoding=self.config.source_encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/io.py", line 107, in __init__
    FileInput.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "/home/federico/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/docutils/io.py", line 236, in __init__
    self.source = open(source_path, mode, **kwargs)
DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
```

And sphinx doesn't load the documentation embedded in the code.

I've been reading that the structure of the project may be responsible but it seems like mine is ok:

```
project/
    docs/
        Makefile
        source/
            conf.py
            index.rst
            modules.rst
    project/
        __init__.py
        foo/
            __init__.py
            modA.py 
            modB.py
        bar/
            __init__.py
            modC.py 
            modD.py
```

Within for instance modA.py I import code like this:

```
import project.foo.modB
```

Relevant bits of some files:

conf.py:

```
...
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
...
```

index.rst:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   modules
```

modules.rst:

```
Modules
*******

Foo
===

.. automodule:: project.foo.modA
   :members:
```

What am I missing here? The imports work fine in the interpreter:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join('/home', 'federico', 'project'))
import project.foo.modB
```

Comment: This is related to deprecation of "universal newline mode" (https://bugs.python.org/issue15204).